# How to display stacked progress bar in a dart command line program?

Tags: dart, command-line, progress-bar

I am making a compile farm implemented in Dart.

Basically, the farm is expected to build 200+ firmware binaries and because of the number of build to process and to reduce the overall duration of the process, I deploy many isolates (aka close notion to thread for Dart) that run concurrently.

Currently, I have 10 isolate running concurrently which process 25 builds in series.

Each isolate shows a progress bar that I "draw" by printing a bar without doing the new line:

```
Stonehenge b5: task ID 2:  Completed   ========================= 100%
```

But because the isolates runs in parallel, the bars are obviously overwritten by each and every isolate.

How would I rather print then as a stack still being able to overwrite each steps while progressing as follows:

```
Stonehenge b5: task ID 2 : =====================•••••••••••••••••••• 50%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 8 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 5 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 6 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 3 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 7 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 9 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 4 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 1 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 10:  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 11:  Completed   ========================= 100%
Stonehenge b5: task ID 0 :  Completed   ========================= 100%
```

Here is how I draw the progress bar:

```dart
const int progressBarLength = 40;
final int progressBar = (data * progressBarLength / 100).floor();
final int remainderBar = progressBarLength - progressBar;

// == Display progress bar
stdout.write(
     '$module: task ID $taskId: ${"".padLeft(progressBar, "=")}${"".padLeft(remainderBar, "•")} ${data.toStringAsFixed(0)}%\r');

if (data == 100) {
  stdout.write(
    "$module: task ID $taskId:  Completed   \n");
}
```

So, how to stack progress bar on screen without issuing clear commands (as I got some information above them)?

Comment: It might make sense to do all of the printing on a single isolate (likely the main isolate), the other isolates can send progress updates via a `SendPort` to the isolate responsible for printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with ANSI escape code:

```
// ANSI escape sequence for moving the cursor up nine lines
const moveCursorUp = '\x1B[9A';

// ANSI escape sequence for clearing the current line
const clearLine = '\x1B[9K';

print('Process running for ${mainDuration.elapsed}'); // nine time

// Move the cursor up nine lines and clear each line
print('$moveCursorUp$clearLine');
```

Logs from the console:

```
Process running for 0:00:04.111440
Process running for 0:00:04.111740
Process running for 0:00:04.111981
Process running for 0:00:04.112189
Process running for 0:00:04.112433
Process running for 0:00:04.112712
Process running for 0:00:04.113011
```